# How does the Max connections and max user connections work in mariaDB

Tags: wordpress, server, mariadb

I have a MariaDB server running 10 databases/users used for 10 different Wordpress sites.

I want to limit the resources so 1 site doesn't consumes it all. I think the max connections and max user connections is the variable I should play with.

So my main question is does `max connections` (default 151) limit the connections to each database or is it shared with all databases on the server?

And how do the `max_user_connections` variable work, is it connections per IP address that request data?

My goal is to limit the each Wordpress site from using to much resources and I want to limit the database connections to a minimum for each site.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[max_connections](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#max_connections) is the total number for the server.

[max_user_connections](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#max_user_connections) is the number per user.

As you have a different user per Wordpress site, setting `max_user_connections` = 15 globally will prevent the use of excessive connections on a single Wordpress site.